# Is there a way to iterate over a list of buttons & toggle a specific button when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iterator, react-hooks

Issue - When I click one button to display answer text, the other button opens too. I only want the answer for each question to be opened when I click on it.

[image]
My Code -

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Questions = [
  {
    question: "What is your favourite colour?",
    answer: "My favourite colour is pink",
  },
  {
    question: "What is your favourite animal?",
    answer: "My favourite animal is a monkey",
  },
]

const FAQs = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen)

  return (
    <div>
      {Questions.map((element, i, array) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={toggle} key={i}>
              {element.question}
            </button>
            {isOpen && <p key={i}>{element.answer}</p>}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default FAQs
```

Comment: This is happening because you're mapping through your questions, and creating a button for each. The onClick function you pass is the same function for each. Essentially both buttons are behaving as your code intends, the value for isOpen when either button is clicked is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `isOpen` to an object, then assign the boolean value as `isOpen[index]=false|true` as required. And in the HTML, bind as `isOpen[i] &&...`

The poblem what you are doing here is that the variable `isOpen` is not related to your `Questions` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `isOpen` to an object and set it like this.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({})
const toggle = (i) => setIsOpen({...isOpen, [i]:!isOpen[i]})
```

Then use it like this

```
<button onClick={() => toggle(i)} key={i}>
    {element.question}
</button>
{isOpen[i] && <p key={i}>{element.answer}</p>}
```

Comment: `i:!isOpen[i]` should be `[i]:!isOpen[i]`

Comment: @Adarsh Mohan Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kimberley Please consider marking the answer as excepted if it worked for you to help people who have the same question in the future.